# Как контролировать число записей в ассоциативной таблице для связи многие-ко-многим?

Tags: sql, база-данных, spring-data, связи, модель-данных

Пишу простое приложение учёта посещаемости студентов.

Есть таблица студент (id, group_id, name, etc).

Есть таблица лекции (id, group_id, subject, time, etc.) (да, скорее всего, это будет не одна таблица, но сейчас не об этом).

Как правильно связать эти таблицы, чтобы количество лекций на 100% совпадало для всех студентов группы??

То есть, для связи многие-ко-многим создается ассоциативная таблица
Attendance (stud_id, lecture_id, attendance_on_lecture),
но при этом, при неаккуратном использовании, может получиться так,
что для одной лекции имеется N записей, а для другой лекции этой же группы и предмета (но в другое время) - M.
Или же наоборот, для двух студентов одной группы будет иметься n и m число записей для лекций по одному предмету.
Можно ли как-то построить модель, чтобы избежать такой ситуации??

Сейчас есть идея организовать взаимодействие с таблицей через хранимые процедуры.

Приложение будет разработано с использованием Spring Data.

Comment: *Как правильно связать эти таблицы* Через таблицу групп. *Можно ли как-то построить модель, чтобы избежать такой ситуации?* Сущность бинарна - или есть посещение, или нет, третьего не дано. А коли так - то фиксироваться должно только одно состояние, для тех, у кого оно не зафиксировано, состояние второе.

Comment: @Akina должно быть быть 3 состояния (есть,нет,опоздал).
_Через таблицу групп_ или я Вас не понял, или что Вы имеете ввиду??